# Handle incoming sockets in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, java-7

I'm trying to do something potentially stupid, but I reckon it's a good idea, so bear with me. I tried to implement it, but I hit an awkward issue with sockets closing between threads - so I want some fresh eyes on the case.

#### Scenario

I want to write an object from a `Client` to a `Server` via sockets. There may be more than one `Client` communicating with the `Server` concurrently.

The object, a `Message`, is handled by the `Server` through its handling mechanisms. It is proposed that instead of the `Server`'s main thread looking out for new incoming connections, a `Listener` thread is set up. Once it spots an incoming connection, it alerts the `Server`, storing the socket in a queue without receiving the data, so it can go back to listening quickly.

In its own time, the `Server` picks up the waiting socket, spawns a new thread, reads the `Message`, and closes the socket.

#### The code

Here's my first thoughts on how this should be implemented. There is a fundamental flaw in it which I will explain below.

Ignore the use of public fields - I'm just trying to make the code short for you guys

```
public class Server {
    public boolean messageWaiting = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        Listener l = new Listener();
        l.listen(this);
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("I'm happily doing my business!");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if (messageWaiting) {
                    acceptMessages(l);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException die) {}
    }

    private void acceptMessages(Listener l) {
        while (!l.waiting.isEmpty()) {
            try (
                Socket client = l.waiting.poll();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream())
            ) {
                // Handle messages in new threads! (or a thread pool)
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(ois.readObject());
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Oh no! The socket has already been closed!
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Listener {
    public ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Socket> waiting = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    public void listen(final Server callback) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try (ServerSocket rxSock = new ServerSocket(7500)) {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        try (Socket client = rxSock.accept()) {
                            // Once a new socket arrives, add it to the waiting queue
                            waiting.add(client);
                            // Alert the server
                            callback.messageWaiting = true;
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (
            Socket txSock = new Socket(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 7500);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(txSock.getOutputStream())
        ) {

            oos.writeObject("This is a Message, trust me.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### What's wrong with this?

This:

```
I'm happily doing my business!
I'm happily doing my business!
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at Server.acceptMessages(Server.java:30)
    at Server.run(Server.java:20)
    at Server.main(Server.java:9)
```

This is because the Java 7 try blocks I'm using close the sockets once they're finished. So why don't I do this manually? Try yourself - you end up with a warning saying you're only ever going to call close() on a null object!

So, how do I avoid the whole issue of my incoming socket being closed before the `Server` thread picks up on it? Or is this a bad idea anyway and I should do something else?

Comment: Why not pass the socket off to a thread immediately after the connection is open?

Comment: I'm doing that, it's just I want the Server to handle Message reception rather than the listener. Why am I doing this? Because my spec needs me to make static methods, sendMessage() and receiveMessage() for both client and server machines. So the server has to know when to call receiveMessage() to get its data.

Comment: Have you tested this code without using a thread yet?

Comment: Yes (other than the listener running on a different thread for obvious reasons)

Comment: Your specification most certainly shouldn't descend to that level of detail, but even if it does there is nothing preventing you from using another thread. You're making a big mistake with the object streams. You must use the same object input & output stream for the life of the socket, at both ends.

Comment: What do you mean by using the same OOS and OIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement in `Listener`

```
try (Socket client = rxSock.accept()) { ...
```

Is a try-with-resources for the *client* socket.  As soon as you add it to the queue and exit the try block, the socket gets auto-closed.

Comment: "This is because the Java 7 try blocks I'm using close the sockets once they're finished. So why don't I do this manually? Try yourself - you end up with a warning saying you're only ever going to call close() on a null object!"
The fact is, if I leave it open it'll complain of leaking, and if I close it at the end of the try, it wont be available to other threads.

Comment: Yes, but the socket gets closed immediately and the thread doesn't execute until after the socket is closed. You need to not use try-with-resources in this inner case.

Comment: That's the point I'm getting at - whether or not I use try-with-resources doesn't matter as if I don't - and just close the socket in the catch clause - I end up with resource leak warnings or null object warnings.

Comment: Actually, it does appear to be fine when I test it without closing the socket. As long as my receiving code closes all client sockets after dealing with them, it should be fine! Right?

Comment: Correct.  The client socket should be closed by the thread that handles the data.